# Can docker containers within same host have same ports

Tags: nginx, docker

I am a noob to docker and I was reading the docs:

> Networks, by definition, provide complete isolation for containers.

Does that mean I can have nginx service on port 80 in each container in the same host, and start each image to use port 80 within it's own container and map the ports:

eg.

```
8080:80 <--- container 1
8081:80 <--- container 2
```

Comment: This the point of port mapping.

Comment: Sure, It will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Did you try this? It should work just fine.